# Where to get a certified "graduate level course work"?

Tags: graduate-admissions, coursework, mooc

I'm interested in applying for a certain PHD. However in the requirments they are asking for graduate-level course work.

I don't understand this exact terminology as I didn't found any course labeled graduate-level. Also what about online MOOC like coursera and edx. They don't provide credit hours, but do they countable?

I will appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Graduate level course work typically refers to courses aimed at master's level students or higher. They are offered by most universities. Sometimes advanced undergraduate students can take these classes in their major in their final year at university. A MOOC is not typically a substitute for an actual class at a university, and moreover are typically not at a high enough level to count as a graduate course. To find out what the specific program is asking for, you need to email someone in admissions at that university and ask what kind of courses qualify as graduate-level course work.

Comment: I'll further point out that depending on location and the requirements of the PhD, they might very well require a full-fledged Master's Degree for admission to the PhD.